# How to check whether the content of Column A is contained in Column B using Python DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns in a pandas DataFrame: `authors` and `name`. I want to create a third column: a cell's value is `True` if the corresponding row's `name` is contained in the corresponding row's `authors`, and `False` otherwise.

So the result will look like the picture below.

[image]

I have tried `.str.contains()`, `.str.extract()`, `.str.find()`, `.where()`, and etc.
But Python returns an error: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.
Does anyone know how to create the third column in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC then you can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a lambda row-wise to check if the Name string is present in Authors:

```
df['Check'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Name'] in row['Authors'], axis=1)
```

should work

You can't use `str.contains()`, `str.extract()`, `str.find()`, or `where()`here because you're trying to compare row-wise and those methods expect a fixed list or pattern for the searching criteria.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and your suggestion solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MattDMo, Thanks a lot for advising. This is the first time that I post question on stackoverflow, and is not very familiar with how to use it. Thanks for reminding!

Comment: @EdChum Hi Ed, I just found out that the following way works as well, just want to share with you : )  :        df['Check'] = map((lambda x,y: x in y),df['Name'], df['Authors']), in Python 2

Comment: Yes that would work it's possible that it's faster as map is implemented as a cython for loop

Comment: @EdChum technically, if you want to be pedantic, `map` is implemented in C, not Cython, but you're close enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized solution, which uses [Series.str.split()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [DataFrame.isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) methods:

```
df['Check'] = df.Authors.str.split(r'\s*,\s*', expand=True).isin(df.Name).any(1)
```

Demo:

```
In [126]: df
Out[126]:
                 Authors     Name
0  S.Rogers, T. Williams   H. Tov
1      M. White, J.Black  J.Black

In [127]: df.Authors.str.split(r'\s*,\s*', expand=True)
Out[127]:
          0            1
0  S.Rogers  T. Williams
1  M. White      J.Black

In [128]: df.Authors.str.split(r'\s*,\s*', expand=True).isin(df.Name)
Out[128]:
       0      1
0  False  False
1  False   True

In [130]: df['Check'] = df.Authors.str.split(r'\s*,\s*', expand=True).isin(df.Name).any(1)

In [131]: df
Out[131]:
                 Authors     Name  Check
0  S.Rogers, T. Williams   H. Tov  False
1      M. White, J.Black  J.Black   True
```