# Compare Columns Row-Wise for Partial String Match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My question is similar to this:
[How to check whether the content of Column A is contained in Column B using Python DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942399/how-to-check-whether-the-content-of-column-a-is-contained-in-column-b-using-pyth?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Unfortunately, the chosen answer results in a nonetype error in my case.

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
id,text_1,text_2_compare
1,yyy,yy
2,yxy,xx
3,zzy,zy
4,zzy,x
5,xyx,yx
```

I would like to compare the columns to see if "text_2_compare" is contained in "text_1" and create an new indicator.

```
id,text_1,text_2_compare,match
1,yyy,yy,1
2,yxy,xx,0
3,zzy,zy,1
4,zzy,x,0
5,xyx,yx,1
```

Any tips or tricks (particularly a vectorized implementation) would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @Onyambu's answer.

`in` can be used in place of `re.findall()`

```
df["match"] = df.apply(lambda v: int(v[2] in v[1]),axis=1)
print(df["match"]
```

**Output:**

```
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    1
```

Comment: I actually thought OP needed the number of times `text_2_compared` appeared in `text_1`, but on reading the question again, it seems OP just wants an indicator variable. Thus `in` is sufficient

Comment: @Onyambu, Oh, that makes sense. Maybe adding this to your answer might help other readers looking for the count instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

df['compare_match']=df.apply(lambda v:len(re.findall(v[2],v[1])),axis=1)

df
   id text_1 text_2_compare  compare_match
0   1    yyy             yy              1
1   2    yxy             xx              0
2   3    zzy             zy              1
3   4    zzy              x              0
4   5    xyx             yx              1
```

EDIT:

I actually thought OP needed the number of times `text_2_compared` appeared in `text_1`, but on reading the question again, it seems OP just wants an indicator variable. Thus using  `v[2] in v[1]` as done above by @gaganso  is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Using simple list

```
df['New']=[int(y in x) for x , y in zip(df['text_1'],df['text_2_compare'])]
df
Out[496]: 
   id text_1 text_2_compare  New
0   1    yyy             yy    1
1   2    yxy             xx    0
2   3    zzy             zy    1
3   4    zzy              x    0
4   5    xyx             yx    1
```